# ByRef argument type mismatch in VBA

Tags: vba

I Wrote code like

```
sub something
    Dim symbols as Symboldetail
    Dim errorSymbols as Symboldetail
    Dim anyError as boolean
    Dim name, id as String
    set symbols = new Symboldetail
    set errorSymbols = new Symboldetail 
    anyerror = funName("","",symbols ,errorSymbols)
end sub

Function funName(ByVal name As String,ByVal id As String, ByRef symbols as Symboldetail,ByRef errorSymbols as Symboldetail) As Boolean
    'here editing the values of symbols and errorSymbols
     funName = false/true
end Fuction
```

when i compile this code it throws error "ByRef argument type mismatch"

i don't know what is the mistake I'm doing

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've got a subroutine and a function with the same name -- why would you do that?  You can't overload when one is a function and one is a subroutine

Comment: also whats `Symboldetail`

Comment: `errorSymbols = False` ? If Symboldetail is a class instance/udt it cannot also be a boolean.

Comment: now i Corrected it, here i wrote wrong but in code those are of different names

Comment: * end fuNction (spelling)

Comment: Then it can't be True/False, have the function *return* the boolean or add a boolean field to the type.

Comment: call funName with all parameters `anyerror = funName(name,id, errorSymbols, symbols )`

Comment: I called with all the vlues but it throwu=ing the same error

Comment: ... and which line is throwing the error?  And is that even the real code, since it still has typos in it?  It's really hard to guess what the problem is with so much wrong.

Comment: it showing error in this line anyerror = funName("","",symbols ,errorSymbols)-> "symbols"

Comment: Usually this happens when you try to pass one element of an array ByRef. We need to see how Symboldetail is defined. It must be a class because you can't use the `New` keyword with a Type. If I set it up as a class, I don't get any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to know what the mistake i did

```
'i declared these variables like 
Dim symbols, errorSymbols as Symboldetail

'instead of 
'Dim symbols as Symboldetail
'Dim errorSymbols as Symboldetail
```

so it is taking symbols as variant instead of Symboldetails, as when i passin the variable it is throwing error as "type mis match error"

@all thanks for valuable comments